# Need understanding of the concept of word (memory)

Tags: memory, cpu, register

I've been reading how memory works from a book. The problem is my weak english so I can't catch the meaning correctly.

The text from the book :

> A computer with a 32-bit word has 4 bytes/word, whereas acomputer with
>   a 64-bit word has 8 bytes/word. The significance of aword is that most
>   instructions operate on entire words, for example, adding two
>   wordstogether. Thus a32-bit machine will have 32-bit registers and
>   instructions for manipulating 32-bit words, whereas a 64-bit machine
>   will have 64-bit registers and instructions for moving, adding,
>   subtracting, and otherwise manipulating 64-bit words.

Before you laugh, I will show my interpretation of the text. The diagram is extracted from the book. Its for *32 bit* case.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your interpretation is correct.

In terms of the line:

"the total is 4 words x 4 bytes = 16 bytes which is 128 bits"

That is the **total** size of the memory. Each word in that memory is 32 bits, and you have 4 of them giving a total size of 128 bits.

Comment: That is for one specific architecture for which those numbers match, including one byte being 8 bits

Comment: My God what wasted hours understanding this. Thank you very much you're hell fast understanding my problem. Genius!

Comment: Btw, so that *32 bits* is refering to a word. So if I say I have 32 bit memory means its *32 bits per word*?

Comment: @Hey-men-whatsup correct.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

*Figure 1. Windows Caculator in Programmer mode. (Menu: View | Programmer.)*

You may find your Windows (or whatever OS you use) calculator helpful in this regard. *Calc* makes the distinction clear by using *Word* for 16-bit, *Dword* (double) for 32-bit and *Qword* (quad) for 64-bit.

In the screengrab shown in Figure 1 I have  selected Qword (4 x 16-bit = 64-bit) and typed in a hexadecimal number.
Here we can see that each hex digit uses a nibble (4-bits): 1 = 0001, 2 = 0010, etc., with all 16 characters using 64 bits.

You may find it instructive to start with *Byte* mode and *Hex* or *Dec* display and start adding numbers (including some negative numbers) to see how it works. When you've got that then go to *Word*, *Dword*, etc.

Comment: Thank you your answer also important for me in the future.

Comment: Not to be picky big guy, but your showing "Word for 16-bit, Dword (double) for 16-bit and Qword (quad) for 32-bit." Should a Dword be 32 bits and a Qword be 64 bits? Occasional typo's are forgiven.

Comment: Ha! What happens if the typos get more regular? Thanks for the tip-off.